# SQL - select rows while joining multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have 3 tables:

**user** / 
**middle table** /
**department**

The middle table and user is many-to-one.
The middle table and department is also many-to-one.

How to get only departments, where is more than one user.

```
| USER |    | MIDDLE TABLE |    |  DEPARTMENT  |
|------|    |--------------|    |--------------|
|id    |----| id           |----| id           |
|      |    | user_id      |    |              |
|      |    | department_id|    |              |
```

EDIT: The user can not be the same user. In this structure, there is possible to have one user in one department many times.

```
| USER   |    | MIDDLE TABLE          |    |  DEPARTMENT  |
|--------|    |-----------------------|    |--------------|
| id |1|2|----| id            |1|2|3|4|----| id |1|2|     |
|        |    | user_id       |1|1|2|1|    |              |
|        |    | department_id |1|1|2|2|    |              |
```

Now I would like to get only department ID: 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple `group by` query:

```
select department_id
from middle_table
group by department_id
having count(distinct user_id) > 1;
```

If a user can only be assigned once to a department, then the `id` column in the middle table is useless and you should make `(user_id, department_id)` the primary key of that table.

If you also need the department information, you can join this:

```
select d.*
from department d
join (
  select department_id
  from middle_table
  group by department_id
  having count(distinct user_id) > 1
) sd on sd.department_id = d.department_id;
```

Comment: There is possible to assign one user more times to department. I already tried this script, but this also give me departments, where is one user more times. :-(

Comment: You said a user can only be assigned once to an department. But as I said initially if you can assign the user more than once you need to use distinct. See my edit

Answer (score 0):

To get the fields in the department table where there is more than 1 employee

```
 SELECT Department.*
 FROM Department WHERE Department.ID IN (
     SELECT department_id
     FROM Middle_table
     GROUP BY Department_id
     HAVING COUNT(user_id) > 1 )
```